# Why can't I use a Linux-based Python interpreter when using PyCharm on a Windows machine?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've heard that I can't use PyCharm (on my Windows machine) that's pointing to a Python interpreter located on a Linux VM.

Any ideas why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can. You can use Docker or Vagrant for doing just that.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/